# I want a create a temp table where the number of columns is equal to the number of columns in an array

Tags: java, sql

I want a create a temp table whose number of columns is equal to the number of columns in an array.
How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Java class method:

```
public String insertExcelDataInTable(String userName, int srNum,String fileName, int fileNum, String[][] data) {

int numOfColumns=data[0].length;

for(int i=1;i<numOfColumns;i++){
String col="col"+i;
System.out.println(col);
 String creatQuery="CREATE TABLE upload_temp (ExcelNumber INT NOT NULL,ExcelName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,..** Number of Columns From an array** ...);";

               }
}
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String insertExcelDataInTable(String userName, int srNum,String 
    fileName, int fileNum, String[][] data) {

    int numOfColumns=data[0].length;
    String creatQuery = "CREATE TABLE upload_temp (ExcelNumber INT NOT NULL,ExcelName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, __COLUMNS_TO_BE_REPLACED__ );";
    String columnsDeclaration = "";

    for(int i=1;i<numOfColumns;i++) {

        String col="col"+i;
        System.out.println(col);
        columnsDeclaration += col + " VARCHAR(100) NULL ";

        if(i < numOfColumns - 1){
            columnsDeclaration += ",";
        }
    }



creatQuery = creatQuery.replace(__COLUMNS_TO_BE_REPLACED__, columnsDeclaration);
return creatQuery;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  to answer Dev_Net you really helped me a lot!

Comment: I am happy that I was helpful :)